# The effect of class member function number

Tags: c++

My question is related to C++ class definition. I understand that if there are many member variables existing in the class. The size of the class will increase. Increasing the number of class member functions, however, will not affect its size. However, I was wondering what is the major difference between a class with more member functions and a class with less member functions. Will it be possible that invoking a class with less member functions is much faster?

Comment: just out of curiosity... how have you come up with this question?

Comment: It will take longer to *compile*, but after that there will be no difference. The compiler figures out how to call each function directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the only kind of functions that make any difference at all this respect are the virtual ones, and they are significantly slower than the usual kind no matter how many you have. In all other cases the compiler knows exactly what code to run when a particular function is called, so it won't have to do any search and the number of methods wouldn't matter.

Comment: *significantly slower* by what standard? Virtual function dispatch is quite efficient, with just one extra indirection in most cases.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas He certainly meant significantly slower than non-virtual member function.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas efficiency is a relative term, of course. However, in really performance-critical bits it might be better to use non-virtual methods.

Comment: @Qnan yes. Image processing is a good example. One extra indirection per pixel makes a *significant* difference.

Comment: @Ugo: Would you really create a `Pixel` type with polymorphic behavior? And I understood what he meant, but in 99.99% of the cases, performance of dynamic dispatch does not make any difference. The point is that *significant* is *insignificant* for most people/applications/use cases. The decision on virtual/non-virtual should be made on the grounds of the design: do you need polymorphic behavior?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas let's say I had some code in which it did make a difference of several percent of the runtime. So *there are cases where virtual methods are significantly slower*. I'm not saying that's always the case.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas Yes of course ... . It is a design choice. The question here is purely technical. And a `Pixel` no, of course, but a Image accessor or a polymorphic algorithm, yes. Take a look a the implementation of the main image processing libraries. You will be surprised how much effort is made to remove this cost.

Answer (score 4):

You need per-instance space to store member variables, but member functions are not part of an instance, at least not directly. There is usually a single extra pointer that is required for each additional virtual member function, but that pointer goes to [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) which is shared among all instances of a class, and therefore does not add to per-member size.

Non-virtual member functions take space only in the code memory: their space requirements are no different from free-standing functions, the only difference being the hidden parameter for passing the pointer to `this`.

The first virtual function added to a class adds an extra pointer to the space required to store an instance; additional non-virtual member functions do not play into space requirements at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, the number of member functions will have no effect on the speed of calling the function (at least with any sane implementation). Any call to a function will just be compiled down to code that sets up the function parameters and then uses the call instruction. The compiler resolves at compile-time what the address of the function is and uses that in the call instruction or, with virtual functions, looks up in a table what address to call.

Answer (score 1):

A class that has fewer functions will not be more efficient than a class with more.

Function efficiency is affected by most significantly by algorithms and I/O.

Compile time however will be affected.